# Equation 11.27 in M.D. Schwartz book

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, spinors

I am having trouble understanding the steps taken in (11.27) equation in *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model* by M.D.Schwartz.

I don't understand how to get the middle diagonal matrix in the second last statement of the equation.

Here is my attempt. I am writing
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \xi_{s'} \\ \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0\\ 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s'} \\ \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} \quad 
and 
\quad \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \xi_{s} \\ \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \xi_{s} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger = \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s} \\ \xi_{s} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0\\ 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger $$

and then proceeding as follows:

$$ \quad \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \xi_s \\ \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \xi_s \end{pmatrix}^\dagger \begin{pmatrix} 0 \ \mathbb{I}_2 \\ \mathbb{I}_2 \ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \xi_{s'} \\ \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad (x) $$

$$  = \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s} \\ \xi_{s} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0\\ 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \ \mathbb{I}_2 \\ \mathbb{I}_2 \ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0\\ 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s'} \\ \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad (a)$$

$$  = \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s} \\ \xi_{s} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0\\ 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \ \mathbb{I}_2 \\ \mathbb{I}_2 \ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0\\ 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s'} \\ \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad (b)$$

$$  = \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s} \\ \xi_{s} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0\\ 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \quad \sqrt{p \cdot \bar \sigma} \\ \sqrt{p \cdot \sigma} \quad 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s'} \\ \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad (c)$$

$$  = \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s} \\ \xi_{s} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \quad \sqrt{(p \cdot \sigma )( p \cdot \bar \sigma)} \\ \sqrt{(p \cdot \bar \sigma )( p \cdot \sigma)} \quad 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s'} \\ \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad (d)$$

Clearly, my middle matrix is very different than the correct* one.
Can anyone please point out or hint what am I doing wrong? Or how the author obtained the middle diagonal matrix?

*Update:
The "correct" expression ( i.e the one given in the book is ):

$$  = \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s} \\ \xi_{s} \end{pmatrix}^\dagger 
\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{(p \cdot \sigma )( p \cdot \bar \sigma)} \quad 0 \\ 0 \quad \sqrt{(p \cdot \sigma )( p \cdot \bar \sigma)}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\xi_{s'} \\ \xi_{s'} \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad (y)$$

To summarize, equation 11.27 says:
$$ (x) = (y) = 2m\delta_{ss'}$$

My main concern is how did the author go from (x) to (y)?

Comment: Examine your third to last equation and the second to last one: you didn't compute the matrix product properly

Comment: Sorry @daydreamer, I still don't see the mistake. There is just one matrix multiplication that I did in going from (b) to (c). I checked it by multiplying 4x4 matrices manually but got the same result that I have mentioned in (c). Were you referring to the same step?

Comment: Sorry I was sleepy when I wrote that. Your product is all right. But, can you please give what "the true answer" should be? Otherwise, in order to obtain a diagonal matrix I'd suggest trying to diagonalize the matrix in the middle of d)

Answer (score 0):

I got the book and think I got it: he just switched columns 1 and 2.
And you can do it without any doubt since your spinor components are "the same"